# Wrapping method returning c++ std::array<std::string, 4> in cython

Tags: python, c++, arrays, string, cython

My method returns `std::array<std::string, 4>` in C++ code. I wrap this code using Cython. I tried to wrap array using memory views. But the result is `Invalid base type for memoryview slice: string`. So can I wrap my `std::array<std::string, 4>` to use it in python like list of strs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to copy to a Python list.

For the sake of this answer I'm assuming you've wrapped your array similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36402807/4657412) and called it `arrstr4`. The code then looks something like:

```
def f():
    cdef arrstr4 res = your_cplus_plus_function()
    py_res = []
    for i in range(4):
        py_res.append(res[i]) # take advantage of autoconversion to python string
    return py_res
```