# Interfacing C++11 array with Cython

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates, cython

I am used to build C++ programs and get it in Cython, but here I am trying to get the C++ 11 `array` and it definitely doesn't work.

Here is my .pxd :

```
cdef extern from "<array>" namespace "std" nogil :
    cdef cppclass array[T, size_t]:
        ctypedef T value_type
        cppclass iterator:
            T& operator*()
            iterator operator++()
            iterator operator--()
            iterator operator+(size_t)
            iterator operator-(size_t)
        bint operator==(iterator)
        bint operator!=(iterator)
        bint operator<(iterator)
        bint operator>(iterator)
        bint operator<=(iterator)
        bint operator>=(iterator)
        T& operator[](size_t)
        array() except +
        array(array&) except +
```

Most of this file is an adaptation from "vector.pxd", but I removed the allocator because c++11 `array` doesn't need it. I used `size_t` as second template argument but I am not sure about it.

The problem is, when I do :

```
    from array11 cimport array
    cdef array[int, 5] test
```

I get, when compiling :

unknown type in template argument

If I do :

```
    from array11 cimport array
    cdef array[int, 5] * test = new array[int, 5]()
```

I get :

> new operator can only be applied to a C++ class

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Does cython have support for non-type templates?

Comment: It may be the right question!

Comment: @AndyG No, it doesn't have support for non-type templates

Comment: Other people have come up with somewhat satisfactory workrounds though. Have a look at the gist of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357024/wrapping-stdarray-in-cython-and-exposing-it-to-memory-views

Comment: So there is no way to implement std::array, without fixed size in the .pxd?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the issue you're having is because Cython doesn't really support non-type template arguments. A workround (hacky and probably fragile) is to trick Cython into thinking it's providing a type template argument:

```
cdef extern from "<array>" namespace "std" nogil :
    cdef cppclass two "2":
        pass

    cdef cppclass array[T, U]:
        T& operator[](size_t)
        # this is obviously very very cut down

def f():
    cdef array[int,two] x
    return x[0]+x[1]
```

The trick is that if you do `cdef cppclass name "somestring"` Cython will just blindly replace `somestring` for name, which generates the correct C++ code. There are obviously some limitations with this approach but for simple usage it should be fine.

Comment: Wow. It may be fragile, it may be hacky, but it's REALLY creative.