# How to use shared_ptr and make_shared with arrays?

Tags: cython, shared-ptr, make-shared

I want to use a C++ shared_ptr as a replacement for raw C pointers. As a simple example the following code seems to work as intended:

```
from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr, allocator

cdef shared_ptr[double] spd 
cdef allocator[double] allo
spd.reset(allo.allocate(13))
```

The size is chosen as 13 here, but in general is not know at compile time.
I'm not sure if this is correct, but I haven't had any errors (no memory leaks and segfaults yet). I'm curious if there is a more optimal solution with make_shared.

But I can't use C++11 arrays because Cython doesn't allow literals as templates, e.g. something like

```
cdef shared_ptr[array[double]] spd = make_shared[array[double,13]]()
```

and "normal" arrays which are supposed to work with C++20 compiler (e.g. gcc 10) are causing problems in one way or another:

```
# Cython error "Expected an identifier or literal"
cdef shared_ptr[double[]] spd = make_shared[double[]](3)    

# Can't get ptr to work
ctypedef double[] darr
cdef shared_ptr[darr] spd = make_shared[darr](13)
cdef double* ptr = spd.get()    # or spd.get()[0] or <double*> spd.get()[0] or ...
```

Is the allocator solution the correct and best one or is there another way how to do it?

Comment: Your solution “works” (it is probably UB) for doubles but will leak memory for more complex classes, as shared_ptr will destruct only the first object but not the other 12. Why not to use std::vector<double> instead of the whole shared_ptr-business?

Comment: Btw array isn’t wrapped in cython, so maybe you did it wrong? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: To my knowledge the std::array class can't be used if the size isn't known at compile time. And even if it's a fairly hacky solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357024/wrapping-stdarray-in-cython-and-exposing-it-to-memory-views).

Comment: I have some use cases where I would want to avoid copying the data when a function returns a "pointer" (hence no vectors), but still need some kind of reference counting (with C pointers I'm doing it manually, shared_ptr would simplify that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I'm going with

```
cdef extern from *:
    """
    template <typename T>
    struct Ptr_deleter{
        size_t nn;
        void (*free_ptr)(T*, size_t);
        Ptr_deleter(size_t nIn, void (*free_ptrIn)(T*, size_t)){
            this->nn = nIn;
            this->free_ptr = free_ptrIn;
        };
        void operator()(T* ptr){
            free_ptr(ptr, nn);
        };
    };
    template <typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr_to_sptr (T* ptr, size_t nn, void (*free_ptr)(T*, size_t)) {
        Ptr_deleter dltr(nn,  free_ptr);
        std::shared_ptr<T> sp (ptr, dltr);
        return sp;
    };
    """
    shared_ptr[double] d_ptr_to_sptr "ptr_to_sptr"(double* ptr, size_t nn, void (*free_ptr)(double*, size_t) nogil) nogil

cdef void free_d_ptr(double* ptr, size_t nn) nogil:
    free(ptr)

cdef shared_ptr[double] sp_d_empty(size_t nn) nogil:
    return d_ptr_to_sptr(<double*> nullCheckMalloc(nn*sizeof(double)), nn, &free_d_ptr)
```

My understanding is that the "right" way to handle `malloc`ed arrays is to use a custom deleter like I did. I personally prefer sticking with somewhat-raw C pointers (`double*` instead of `double[]` or something), since it's more natural in Cython and my projects.

I think it's reasonably easy to see how to change `free_ptr` for more complicated data types. For simple data types it could be done in less lines and less convoluted, but I wanted to have the same base.

I like my solution in the regard that I can just "wrap" existing Cython/C code raw pointers in a `shared_ptr`.

When working with C++ (especially newer standards like C++20) I think verbatim code is pretty often necessary. But I've intentionally defined `free_d_ptr` in Cython, so it's easy to use existing Cython code to handle the actual work done to free/clear/whatever the array.

I didn't get C++11 `std::arrays` to work, and it's apparently not "properly" possible in Cython in general (see [Interfacing C++11 array with Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190519/interfacing-c11-array-with-cython)).

I didn't get `double[]` or similar to work either (is possible in C++20), but with verbatim C++ code I think this should be doable in Cython. I prefer more C-like pointers/arrays anyway as I said.